# CSS. Как зафиксировать щирину выпадающего блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вот простые примеры выпадающих блоков:
[Пример 1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXgPaL)
[Пример 2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwyaNJ)

Подскажите пожалуйста как зафиксировать ширину выпадающего блока?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 20%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте HTML код чтоли...

Comment: AGS17 Так по ссылка "Пример 1" и "Пример 2" все есть.

Comment: Добавил код сюда.

Comment: хоть посмотрели бы что вставляете... HTML и JS из одного примера, CSS из другого...

Comment: JS был из другого. Извиняюсь..

Comment: @AndrewF. А в чём вопрос? Что значит зафиксировать? Установите фиксированное значение `width`, вот и будет ширина "зафиксирована".

Answer (score 2):

Вот первый способ изменив каркас `html`.
И добавив для `button`-а и выпадающего меню ширину на `100%`

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.menu_container{
  width: 200px;
}
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_container">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

А этот вариант с помощю ՝javascript՝ при открытии задаем ширину выпадающего меню на ширину `button`.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    panel.style.width = this.offsetWidth+"px";
    
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 40%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #444;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Свойство `height`, указанное в *%*, работает только если для внешнего блока указана высота.
Стандарт *CSS 2.1* предоставляет обход этой проблемы, отдельно указывая, что проценты работают при `position:absolute`. На практике это часто выручает.
Если у родительского элемента не установлено `height`, а указано `min-height`, то, чтобы дочерний блок занял *100%* высоты, нужно родителю поставить свойство `height: 1px`.

Comment: Ваш ответ [даже частично не отвечают на фактический вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме того при использовании [чужих работ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) необходимо предоставлять ссылку на [оригинал](https://learn.javascript.ru/height-percent#итого)